# Add border around TextSpan in RichText widget

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a `RichText` widget that contains some `TextSpan`. Around a `TextSpan` widget I want to place a border around it.

```
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    style: textStyle,
    children: [ ], // code has more TextSpan widgets as children
  ),
```

This is an example of the effect I am trying to achieve in Flutter.

[image: border around text]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Paint paint = Paint()
  ..color = Colors.blue
  ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
  ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
  ..strokeWidth = 2.0;

RichText(
                    text: TextSpan(children: [
                  TextSpan(text: '123'),
                  TextSpan(text: '456', style: TextStyle(background: paint)),
                  TextSpan(text: '789')
                ]))
```

Comment: How can we add some padding between the border and the text?

Answer (score 4):

Use a `WidgetSpan` if you want to do more interesting things like add padding.

```
Text.rich(
  TextSpan(
    text: 'Lorem ipsum',
    children: [
      WidgetSpan(
        alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.middle,
        baseline: TextBaseline.ideographic,
        child: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 1),
          ),
          child: const Text('dolor sit amet,'),
        ),
      ),
      const TextSpan(text: 'consectetur'),
    ],
  ),
);
```