# How to use Flutter to achieve mixed arrangement of widgets and text

Tags: android, flutter, dart

To achieve a UI effect, the widget and text are in one line, and the text is behind the widget.

Comment: Please read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so that we can better assist you.

Comment: I get it.
Can you see my picture？

Comment: Did you try using Stack?

Comment: No, I am going to try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with the Richtext Widget. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52553956/add-border-around-textspan-in-richtext-widget) provide a good approach to it:

Comment: Thank you very much, it solved my problem perfectly.